# Can I set up SQL Server Authentication in database A so a stored procedure can read data in database B?

Tags: sql-server, authentication

Thanks in advance for reading!

Note:  I've read everything else I could find about this on SO, but don't see this particular question asked.

I don't want to muddy (or break) our 3rd party production ERP database ("B") with objects of my own, so I created a database ("A") in another instance and use it as the home of various objects that serve our custom applications.

I have a stored procedure in A that selects from tables in B, and returns a dataset.  It works beautifully for me from my app using Windows authentication, because I am an admin on both servers.  But I am one of the rare users who have Windows Authentication in the ERP db.  By default, users in the ERP are created with SS authentication.

If it's a reasonable practice (and because maintenance of my objects would be simpler than with certificates), would it make sense/be possible to create a SQL authenticated user on A (and maybe B) that has execute permissions on the sp in A and read permissions on tables in B?

If not, and in order to avoid dealing with certificates whenever I modify a procedure, I'll probably create server logins on A and B for new Active Directory groups, and create database roles for the groups.

Thanks again for your interest!

Comment: See [this](http://sommarskog.se/grantperm.html#crossdb) and all the related materials. The certificate hoopla can be automated with DDL triggers, although it's not exactly simple. Avoiding certificates entirely would probably mean doing unsafe things with cross-db ownership chaining/`TRUSTWORTHY`, which may or may not be acceptable on your setup.

Comment: First of all, WHO should be able to execute your stored proc? If you have Windows login on A that should access data on B and your question is "can I map this win login to some SQL Login on linked server?" the answer is yes you can

Comment: Thanks all.  Jeroen, I don't want to use cross-db ownership against the ERP.  Sepupic, If I'm going to use windows auth at all, I'll just use the AD groups solution and add/remove users as needed.  I've done it before, it works well.  It allows network admins to configure new network users for the db without having to create accounts in the database, and I don't have to add them in the db.

Comment: My objective was to make some applications independent of the current user's windows session, and connect with a specific sql login that had only the necessary permissions for the task at hand.

Comment: I still don't understand what yoy want. You have SQL Server logins on server B that already have necessary permissions. Now you want to access data from server A using some of already existing login on B, correct? What is your problem?

Comment: >>>My objective was to make some applications independent of the current user's windows session, and connect with a specific sql login<<< That is what I was talking about. You already have some SQL Server login on server B with all the necessary permissions. Now you want to access from server A using this login. So what is your problem? How to map some existing windows login on A to SQL Server login on B? Do you want to map ALL the existing logins on A to that SQL Server login on B? Or smth else?

Comment: I apologize if I am not being clear.  Yes, I have identically named sql server logins/users on A and B.  The login on A can execute the sp (which reads data from B), and the login on B has read permissions on the necessary tables in B.  But the two databases don't recognize each other's server logins.  I don't expect them to, but I was wondering if there is a simple workaround that doesn't involving certificates or linking the servers.

Comment: sepupic, I don't think mapping works across two instances of sql server, does it?